# Why is the output 16 and not 11?

Tags: javascript, math, operators, integer-arithmetic

I was learning javascript and I came across the following example,

```js
let n = 2;

n *= 3 + 5;

console.log( n );
```

Since we have used  "*=" in the expression I thought the expression is supposed to be n = n * 3+5. If the expression is n = n * 3+5 then shouldn't we get 11? I am getting 16 as the answer. Can someone please explain why is the answer 16 and not 11 ?

Comment: see: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: You are correct that `*` would have a higher priority than `+`; but `*=` has a lower priority than `+`. As a rule of thumb, an operator which has the symbol `=` inside it will have a lower priority that an operator which doesn't. However, in this particular case I think it would have been more elegant to write `n *= (3 + 5);` with parentheses. Although the parentheses are redundant and not necessary, they make it easier to read for a human.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it follows the order of operation. `+` has a higer priority than `*=` so if we add brackets to the statement to see it clearer, it would be something like:

```
let n = 2;
n *= (3 + 5)
// which means n = n * (3 + 5)
// which is n = n * 8
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table

Answer (score 1):

Well,
There is a hidden parentheses in the 2nd line which means, it must look like this
n*=(3+5) >> 8 then 16

Answer (score 1):

Its based on the priority and the order

1. **/,*,%** ---> calculated from Left to right.

2.**+ ,-** ---> calculated from Left to right

3. **+=,-=,*=,/=,%=,&=,^=,|=,>>=,<<=** ---> calculated from Right to left